# linearizing if-then with two binary invoved

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I need to linearize this $\alpha_i^{ap}=1 \implies \beta_{ij}^{ap} =1 $. As both are binary,
I think the right answer is $ \alpha_i^{ap} \ge \beta_{ij}^{ap} $. But rading one of the questions a the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849066/linearization-of-if-then-constraint) by @Erwin Kalvelagen makes me to wonder whether that's really correct.  When I apply that method it doesn't seem to be correct either. Whcih one is correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the inequality backwards.  It should instead be $\alpha_i^{ap} \le \beta_{ij}^{ap}$.  Here's a derivation using conjunctive normal form:
$$
x \implies y \\
\lnot x \lor y \\
(1 - x) + y \ge 1 \\
x \le y
$$